# How to enable error log in Ubuntu Apache

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, error-log

How can I enable error log on my Ubuntu Apache Server so that if any error occurs be it any PHP Syntax and other errors, server error should get stored in error log file

Also how can I view apache error log file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default, `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

This can be configured in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

You can also define a specific error log file for each VirtualHost in Apache. If you have any VirtualHost defined in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and enabled in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` (enable with `sudo a2ensite [your-virtualhost-definition-file]`), you can change the error log by adding the following line inside your VirtualHost config:

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/[your-vhost]-error.log
```

That might be useful if you have a lot of vhosts and want to split where they report the errors.

Also, you can watch your error log live by issuing the following command (adapt to your own log file if different from the default):

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

For more information check out the following links

- [where-are-the-apache-and-php-log-files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14763/where-are-the-apache-and-php-log-files)
- [HTTPD - Apache2 Web Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/httpd.html)
- [how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-apache-on-an-ubuntu-vps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-apache-on-an-ubuntu-vps)